# Handling requests, FilterDispatcher vs DispatcherServlet

Tags: spring, struts2

For Requests handling, struts 2 uses `FilterDispatcher` whereas Spring uses Servlet(dispatcher servlet) for dispatching the requests. What difference does this make? I mean they are doing the same job that is handling the incoming requests but using different strategies, one is using servlet other is using filter dispatcher.

Comment: It's just a matter of taste, you can implement a dispatcher using a filter or a servlet. By the way I myself believe Servlet is better, because Servlets are created for handling request, but Filters are created for intercepting requests.

Comment: there is a good discussion going on struts mailing list about same here is link for you http://struts.1045723.n5.nabble.com/Benefits-of-using-Filter-as-front-controller-td5710406.html

Answer (score 0):

`Struts2` and `spring mvc` are different web frameworks that follow `mvc` design pattern. The architecture of both differs. Since they are different frameworks, they have different ways of achieving the same thing i.e. request handling. You can read more about `FilterDispatcher` [here](http://struts.apache.org/2.1.6/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/dispatcher/FilterDispatcher.html).

Comment: thanks all. what i mean is in struts2 filter dispatcher was introduced instead of Servlet that must have been because of some reason..what is that reason...